# iPhone Status/Overview App Wanted

Tags: iphone, applications, system-information

I often have my iPhone connected to my PC and now I have a question about something like a status app.

I thought of something like this information:
- a big clock
- signal strength
- mobile signal technology (2g/3g)
- charge status

I thought of something like an overview/status app because I connect my iPhone through a 6-cm cable and so I could see the infos from about 30-40 cm distance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any app that does exactly this. The closest I've seen is [System Status](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-status-activity-manager/id401457165?mt=8), which is an Activity Monitor-style app that has a big battery status display, as well as lots of other info on free memory, device space, running processes, etc.

Something that does exactly what you're looking for is unlikely, as there are no public APIs for getting the device signal strength. Any such app wouldn't be allowed in the App Store. It is conceivable you could make something for a jailbroken device.

Perhaps just position the phone closer on your desk, as all that information is readily available in the standard iOS status bar.