# Is there a way to have my iPhone 5 report current charging rate?

Tags: iphone, usb, charging

For example, so I can test different USB ports on my computer and powered hubs to see if one charges my iPhone faster than another.

Comment: If you don't want this to be duplicate, feel free to edit in you want to get this data from the device itself or from a computer other than Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS can indicate the charge in percentages, you could simply get a pencil and some graph paper and wake the screen periodically and record the displayed percentages to fit that data to a charging curve.

We have some questions about getting the charge rate programmatically in iTunes, and you could ask if there is an API (private or public) by opening a question on http://stackoverflow.com but for users (as opposed to developers), the answer is no. You can't get a log file of the charge status directly from a computer or the device itself.

Here are some related questions that may help:

- [Can I get iPhone charge status from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46335/can-i-get-iphone-charge-status-from-my-mac)
- [iPhone Status/Overview App Wanted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57191/iphone-status-overview-app-wanted)