# View iPhone charging rate

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

At my office, I have a 3rd-party wall adapter, a 3rd-party microUSB cable, and a 3rd-party wireless charging dock. My iPhone X charges slowly on this setup, compared to at home. I suspect that the cable is the weak link, but I'd like to know for sure.

I don't want to sit around with a stopwatch and measure charging rate over time, as suggested in [this 2013 answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90933/is-there-a-way-to-have-my-iphone-5-report-current-charging-rate). I want to use an app or built-in reporting to see how quickly the phone is charging. Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016, it seems this was only possible using unpublished APIs (see [this article](https://www.macstories.net/ios/testing-apples-29w-usb-c-power-adapter-and-ipad-pro-fast-charging/)), ergo impossible without a custom app.

I suspect it's gotten more difficult since as advertisers have been caught using battery levels as a form of device fingerprinting (see [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkoetsier/2021/04/01/apple-rejecting-apps-with-fingerprinting-enabled-as-ios-14-privacy-enforcement-starts/?sh=38eaaaba3d19)) and Apple has been rejecting apps that use accurate battery data as a result. Thus, it might not even be possible anymore to get accurate battery levels with any app on the App Store.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't thought about fingerprinting, makes sense. Too bad there's nothing built-in.